# Python - Call a Function on a Condition

Tags: python, if-statement, ternary-operator

I was wondering if there is a concise way to call a function on a condition.

I have this:

```
if list_1 != []:
    some_dataframe_df = myfunction()
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to this in a [ternary operator](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) or something similiar.

If I do

```
(some_dataframe_df = myfunction()) if list_1 != [] else pass
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: That first bit of code is fine. Trying to reduce it further will like just convolute the point of it. Smaller isn't always better.

Comment: Also, instead of `list != []`, it's a better pattern to use `if not list_1:`. This will evaluate to true/false if "iterable" is empty.
That allows for the correct check for all zero-lenth iterables, even it's a different type of iterable (tuble, dict keys, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine. The only change I suggest is to use the inherent Truthness of non-empty lists:

```
if list_1:
    some_dataframe_df = myfunction()
```

If you wish to use a ternary statement it would be written as:

```
some_dataframe_df = myfunction() if list_1 else some_dataframe_df
```

However, this is neither succinct nor readable.

Answer (score 2):

In ternary operator, the conditionals are an expression, not a statement. Therefore, you can not use `pass` and normal `if` statement that you have used is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pass` seems like a bad idea in a ternary operator, especially since you can inline a single-statement `if`.

If you are not worried about your list being `None`, you can shorten the test to just use the boolean value of the list itself. This has the advantage that it will allow any normal sequence, not just lists.

All in all, you could do something like:

```
if list_1: some_dataframe_df = myfunction()
```