# Python Pandas Update Conditional on DF2 Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1

       hair    eyes   gender  

joe     br      bl      m
mary    bl      br      f
pete    rd      gr      m
```

and I want to update df1 with values from df2 IF subject to some values in some additional columns

```
       hair    eyes   gender  weight  height

joe     bk      gr      m       150     72
mary    bl      br      f       125     55
pete    rd      gr      m       180     68
```

I want to do this:

```
df1.update(df2)   #if df2 height is over 70
```

but not sure how or if it's possible to specify condition.

The output I'd get after the operation is:

```
       hair    eyes   gender  

joe     bk      gr      m
mary    bl      br      f
pete    rd      gr      m
```

So only Joe was updated because his height was over 70.

Is there some way to conditionally specify `update` or is it best to just make another df where `df2['height'] > 70`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter `df2` *before* you update:

```
df1.update(df2[df2['height'] > 70])
```

Comment: I read the documentation and it wasn't clear that I could do that.  But I guess I can!  Thanks.

Comment: @Windstorm1981, No problem. Consider accepting the answer (and [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229230/python-call-a-function-on-a-condition) if it helped).